# Listing Google Drive folder content with a Google Script App takes very long

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am writing a Google App Script to list and write the content of a Google Drive Folder in a Google Sheet. The folder is huge (more than 150Go and some subfolders have depth up to 10) so that it cannot be done in a single iterative run. I had to use an other method (less efficient but which allows to run the same script many times). I use triggers (I run it every 10mn).

First, I initialize the Google Sheet with the root folder with a "to-do" flag.
The script then works as the following:
Using a for loop starting at the first "to-do" flag, it reads each line of the Google Sheet (getRange().getValues): if the line is a folder with a "to-do" flag, it lists (using getFiles and getFolders) and writes (setValues) all its direct subfiles  and subfolders (folders are flagged as "to-do") and then the script flags the current folder as "done", so that it is not read on the next run. If the line is a file, it does nothing.
Thus, I can list and write on the google sheet all the element of depth 0, then depth 1, then depth 2, etc.

It works but it is soooo long. Some of the functions (setValues, getValues, getRange) sometimes takes around 60 seconds (whereas a regular loop takes up to 1s when there is no such anormal delay), which drastically limits the number of folders the script can explore on each run...

I tried to use the fluch method and the sleeper (up to 5 seconds) to be sure each operation is finished when I start the next loop but it takes very long.

Is this a normal behavior ? Is there any tricks to bypass this limitation ?

If needed I can post the code!

Thanks a lot,
Asan

Edit : here is the code I use :

`

```
var TODO_FLAG = "To-do";
var DONE_FLAG = "Done";
var DOING_FLAG = "Trop long";

function listFullTree(){

  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONTENT_SHEET);

  var statusColumn = currentSheet.getRange(1, 1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getValues().flat();
  var i = statusColumn.indexOf(TODO_FLAG);
  
  if (i == -1){
    return
  }

  var nbRows = currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var nbColumns = currentSheet.getLastColumn();

  var premier_passage = true;

  while (i <= nbRows){

    var currentRange = currentSheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, nbColumns);
    var currentRow = currentRange.getValues()[0];
    
    if (premier_passage) {
      currentSheet.getRange(i+1, 1).setValue(DOING_FLAG);
    }

    if (currentRow[3] == "Dossier" & currentRow[0] == TODO_FLAG){

      var id = currentRow[11];
      var folderName = currentRow[2];
      var parentPath = currentRow[1];
      var depth = currentRow[4];

      try{
        var folderName = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getName();

        /** 
         * Write folders
         */ 
        var rows = getChildFolders(id, parentPath + "/" + folderName, depth+1);
        var nbFolders = rows.length;

        if (nbFolders > 0){
          currentSheet.getRange(nbRows + 2, 1, nbFolders, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
        }

        /** 
         * Write files
         */ 
        var rows = getChildFiles(id, parentPath + "/" + folderName, depth+1);
        var nbFiles = rows.length;

        if (nbFiles > 0) {
          currentSheet.getRange(nbRows + nbFolders +2, 1, nbFiles, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);

          var size = 0;
          for(var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
            size = size + rows[j][10];
          }
        }

        currentSheet.getRange(i+1,nbColumns-2,1,3).setValues([[nbFiles, nbFolders, size]])
        currentSheet.getRange(i+1, 1).setValue(DONE_FLAG);

        nbRows = nbRows + nbFiles + nbFolders;
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        currentSheet.getRange(i+1, 1).setValue(e);
      }
    }`
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script? By the way, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What does `150Go` of `The folder is huge (more than 150Go and some subfolders have depth up to 10)` mean? Is that the number of folders or files? If that is not the number of folders and files, can I ask you about the approximate number of folders and files?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your answer! The approximate number of folders + files is around 50.000! I edited my first post and added the code!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided information, when I could correctly understand your current situation, I would like to thin of a solution.